# uicollectionview crashing rotating iPad fast

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I usually don't ask for help but this time I really need it.
I have an `UICollectionView`into an `UIViewController`. I have tried using default `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` or subclassing it trying to solve this annoying problem.
When I started to rotate the app so fast (from portrait to landscape and going back to portrait) I'm getting this errors:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionViewData validateLayoutInRect:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2935.138/UICollectionViewData.m:357
```

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UICollectionView recieved layout attributes for a cell with an index path that does not exist:  {length = 2, path = 2 - 4}'

What I have tried:

1. Under `viewWillLayoutSubviews` I have tried with `[self.collectionView reloadData];` or `[self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];`
2. `setting [UIView setAnimationEnabled: NO]; in willRotateToInterfaceOrientation setting [UIView setAnimationEnabled: YES]; in didRotateToInterfaceOrientation`
3. Tried what I found in this link [UICollectionView assertion error on stale data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18339030/uicollectionview-assertion-error-on-stale-data)

Digging about similar problems I found those 3 but none of them is what I'm looking for:

- [Crash when reloading collectionView frequently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25422588/crash-when-reloading-collectionview-frequently)
- [UICollectionView performBatchUpdates cause collectionview misplace while rotating the device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19396440/uicollectionview-performbatchupdates-cause-collectionview-misplace-while-rotatin)
- [UICollectionView recieved layout attributes for a cell with an index path that does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24784877/uicollectionview-recieved-layout-attributes-for-a-cell-with-an-index-path-that-d)

All the data is downloaded before show the`UICollectionView` and I'm using cell created in XIB.
I guess it's about spamming invalidateLayout because the `UICollectionView` has not finished the last "layout process" when the app is calling invalidateLayout again... but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a long time since I posted this question, but I had to come back to the project in where I was using this code and I found that the problem was solved for Apple in iOS release 8.3.

Details: [link](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1806?viewlocale=en_US&locale=es_LA)

> Orientation and rotation fixes
>   * Addresses an issue that sometimes prevented rotating back to portrait after having rotated to landscape
>   * Improves performance and stability issues that occurred when rotating the device between portrait and landscape

I tested it in 2 devices and is working perfectly